# Framework to create a questionnaire following simple workflow, with final report

Tags: survey, workflow

My task:

developing a simple application for classifying a river health.
The user is requested to answer a series of questions.
Every question has a close set of allowed answers which may be filtered by previous choices and next question is chosen based primarily on the last answer but may be influenced by older choices too. 
At the end the application gives the health status of the river and a report with all question/answer can be printed.

Can a workflow framework simplify my work ?

The framework I'm looking for should have most of the following characteristics:

- free to use
- well documented with tutorials and examples
- the application should be easy to distribute and install

The last requisite push toward a library for web application or something I can easily integrate in a desktop application without the need to be installed separately.

Answer (score 0):

## [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/)

It includes a page navigation built-in feature that could be used as a "workflow framework" as was described in the question.

### Requirements Fulfillment

> - free to use

Yes

---

> - well documented with tutorials and examples

Yes, there a lot of material created by Google and users.

---

> - the application should be easy to distribute and install

No installation required, but it requires Internet connection.

---

### Appendix

From [Control your form's page-to-page navigation - Docs editors help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en)

> ### Control your form's page-to-page navigation
>
> If you've divided your form into different pages by adding page
>   breaks, you can specify which users see which pages depending on their
>   answers to questions in your form — sort of like a “Choose Your Own
>   Adventure” story. For example, you can send users who answer “Yes” to
>   a question to page three of your form while sending users who answer
>   “No” to page four.
>
> #### Here’s how to send users to a specific page based on their answer to a certain question:
>
> 1. Create a form.
> 2. From the Insert menu, select either Multiple Choice or Choose from a list. (Note: Only these two question types can be used to direct
>      respondents to specific pages. No other question type can.)
> 3. Check the box labeled Go to page based on answer.
> 4. Next to your answers for this question, you'll see drop-down menus which allow you to direct respondents to specific pages in your form
>      depending on their answers. (Note: If you have more than one question
>      with the “Go to page based on answer” box checked on a page, the form
>      respondent will be routed to the page indicated for the last answered
>      question. Otherwise, two “Go to page based on answer” questions might
>      contradict one another. You can also choose to send respondents to the
>      confirmation page based on an answer by selecting Submit form from the
>      drop-down menu.)
>
> #### Here’s how to send users from one page to another specific page:
>
> Suppose you’ve sent some respondents to page three in your form and
>   you’d like them to see page five, and not page four, next.
>
> 1. Create a form.
> 2. Divide your form into pages by adding page breaks. From the Insert menu, select Page Break.
>
>    - If you’d like, you can name your page break and add a description. This might help you remember where you’re directing respondents, and
>        it may also help respondents understand the structure of your form.
> 3. At the end of each page in your form, you’ll see a dropdown menu with options for where to send respondents next. By default, it’s set
>      to “Continue to next page,” but you can change it to send respondents
>      to a specific page in your form or to the form’s confirmation page.
>      (Note: If a page has a "Go to page based on answer" multiple choice
>      question on it, the respondent's answer to that question will override
>      any page navigation settings you’ve chosen.)

Comment: Google forms seems proimising but I need few days to evaluate it better